# Scikit-Learn + Scipy.optimize external optimizers in Gaussian Processes regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I am using the Gaussian Processes regression from Scikit-learn for the first time and I would like to use `scipy.optimize` external optimizers in:

```py
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, alpha=0.015, normalize_y=True, optimizer= EXT_OPT).
```

What is the correct way to use external optimization library?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I figured it out myself. It is quite easy as follows:

```py
def optimizer(obj_func, initial_theta, bounds):
    optimResult = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj_func, initial_theta,  method='L-BFGS-B', jac=False)
    theta_opt = optimResult.x0
    func_min = optimResult.fun
    return theta_opt, func_min
```

OR

```py
def optimizer(obj_func, initial_theta, bounds):
    theta_opt, func_min, _ = opt.fmin_l_bfgs_b(obj_func, initial_theta, bounds=bounds)
    return theta_opt, func_min
```

```py
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, alpha=0.015, normalize_y=True, optimizer=optimizer)
```